# Instapaper-like service for YouTube

Tags: youtube, offline

Is there an Instapaper-like system for YouTube videos?

**Objective**: to be able to mark YouTube videos for later playback, then be able to watch them later on my phone while I'm on the subway.

Failing this, is there a workflow through which I can accomplish this, by like generating my own podcast that I subscribe to via iTunes?

Comment: YouTube has had a "watch later" function for some time now.

Answer (score 2):

A new service debuted at Techcrunch Disrupt. It's called [Spool](https://getspool.com/). It lets you download text, video, audio etc. to your phones for offline viewing.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

[wacchen.com](http://wacchen.com/)

EDIT: This service seems to no longer exists. Thanks @Boris Terzic

Comment: Domain is "empty", Dreamhost default page. Sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have internet access in the subway, you could bookmark the videos using a social bookmarking service (such as [Delicious](http://delicious.com/)) and then follow the links on your phone.

Both services have mobile versions:

- [Delicious](http://m.delicious.com/)
- [YouTube](http://m.youtube.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I created a service called [Tubelivery](http://tubelivery.com) that creates podcasts from YouTube channels.

It won't work exactly the way you want (with your own playlist) but you can add your favorite channels and subscribe to them as a podcast.